# Error while creating Report Data Source and SSRS Report in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, reporting-services, report-builder

I have a SharePoint Server 2016 Enterprise Edition farm with SQL Server 2016 Standard edition as the DB server. I successfully installed the SQL Server 2016 Reporting Service Add-in for SharePoint 2016 and also successfully provisioned SSRS Service Application and added SSRS content types to document library. But I am not able to resolve the below error while I try to create a Report Data Source or a SSRS Report.

Has any one resolve this type of error before? Please share your experience.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I tried with IE 11 and Edge, both 32-bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a bit on web, I found the Service Pack 1 for Reporting Services Add-in for SharePoint 2016. I had already installed Reporting Services Add-in on SharePoint WFE but SP1 was missing. I installed it on my SharePoint WFE and finally the above error disappeared.

Microsoft SQL Server 2016 SP1 Reporting Services Add-in for Microsoft SharePoint
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54268

Following steps I followed:

1. I installed SQL Server 2016 Reporting Service Add-in Service Pack 1 on my SharePoint 2016 WFE server
2. Restarted the Server
3. Deleted SSRS Service Application
4. Recreated SSRS Service Application
5. Created a new Web Application and associate with recreated SSRS Service Application
6. Created a new site collection and added the SSRS content types to a document library and thereafter was able to successfully create Report Source and launch Report builder.